# TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im making a dashboard for a Discord Bot, but i keep getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined. The code of my app is:

```js
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const client = require("./Client");
const express = require('express');
const reqip = require('request-ip');
const passport = require('passport');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const session = require('express-session');
const getFilesSync = require("..//Utils/fileWalk");
const SQLiteStore = require("connect-sqlite3")(session);
const { Strategy } = require('passport-discord').Strategy;
const port = process.env.port || 80;

class App {
  constructor(locals = {}) {
    this.express = express();
    this.express.set("view engine", "ejs");
    this.express.set("port", port);
    this.express.set("json spaces", 2);
    this.express.locals = locals;
    
    / * MiddleWare Functions * /;
    this.express.use(express.json());
    this.express.use(express.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    }))
    
    this.express.use(reqip.mw());
    this.express.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + "/../Assets"));

    bindAuth(this.express, client);

    this.express.use(passport.initialize());
    this.express.use(passport.session());
    this.express.use(async (req, res, next) => {
      req.bot = client;
      next();
    });

  this.loadRoutes().loadErrorHandler();
  }

  listen(port) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => this.express.listen(port, resolve));
  }

  loadRoutes() {
    const routesPath = path.join(__dirname, "../routes");
    const routes = getFilesSync(routesPath);

    if (!routes.length) return this;

    routes.forEach((filename) => {
      const route = require(path.join(routesPath, filename));

      const routePath =
        filename === "index.js" ? "/" : `/${filename.slice(0, -3)}`;

      try {
        this.express.use(routePath, route);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error occured with the route "${filename}"\n\n${error}`);
      }
    });

    return this;
  }

  loadErrorHandler() {
    this.express.use((req, res) => {
      res.status(404);

      if (req.accepts("html")) return res.render("404", {req});

      if (req.accepts("json"))
        return res.send({
          status: 404,
          error: "Not found",
        });

      res.type("txt").send("404 - Not found");
    });

    return this;
  }
}


function bindAuth(app, client) {
  app.use(session({store: new SQLiteStore(), secret: "nosecretlol", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}))

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
  })

  passport.use(
    new Strategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.bot_id,
        clientSecret: process.env.bot_secret,
        callbackURL: process.env.bot_redirect,
        scope: ["identify", "guilds"]
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
          profile.tokens = { accessToken }
          return done(null, profile)
        })
      })
    )
  }

module.exports = App;
```

And in my index i make my app like this:

```js
const App = require("myfile");
(async () => {
await new App().listen(process.env.port || 80)
})()
```

The error says is in: node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:139:34)
I tried with all and i cannot solve this, i asked many persons but no ones give me a answer that can solve my question.
Like i said this is for a Discord Bot Dashboard

Comment: Can you identify the line of app code, in the error trace message, that called into express and generated the internal error? If you can, please edit the question to include the details rather than adding a comment below.